# Finite groups all of whose subgroups are CLT

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, solvable-groups

A $CLT$-group is a finite group with the property that for every divisor of the order of the group,
there is a subgroup of that order (converse lagrange theorem).

I know that:

- There is a $CLT$-group with a non-$CLT$ subgroup (e.g., $S_4$).
- Every subgroup of a supersolvable group is a  $CLT$-group (because every 
  supersolvable group is $CLT$ and it subgroups are all supersolvable).

Now, my question:

**(Q1)** Is there a **name (or an easy criterion)** for groups all of  whose subgroups are $CLT$?

**(Q2)** Does anybody know an example of such groups that is not supersolvable?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since every subgroup of a supersolvable group is supersolvable,
and every supersolvable group is CLT, it follows that if $G$ is supersolvable, then every subgroup of $G$ is CLT. W. Deskins (see *A Characterization of Finite Supersolvable Groups*, Am. Math. Monthly Vol. 75, No. 2 (1968)) proved that $G$ is supersolvable if and only if every subgroup of $G$ is CLT. With this, I think you can answer Q2 yourself...

Comment: This also answers Q1 (+1)